# How to check for username and email in nestjs validation. The async function awaits for findbyusername and then never reaches the else condition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, nestjs

How to check for username and email in nestjs validation. The async function awaits for findbyusername and then never reaches the else condition.

I am trying to create one validation method to check if entered value in `userNameorEmail`  field is username or email but looks like the function never reaches to the else statement. It just throws the error when I do `then` and `catch`. How can I make it work.  Thanks for your help in advance.

```
  async validateUser(userNameorEmail: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {

    const resultByUsername = await this.usersService.findbyUsername(userNameorEmail);

    if (resultByUsername && resultByUsername.password === pass) {
      const { password, ...result } = resultByUsername;
      return result;

    } else {
      const resultByEmail = await this.usersService.findbyEmail(userNameorEmail);

      if (resultByEmail && resultByEmail.password === pass) {
        const { password, ...result } = resultByEmail;
        return result;

      }
    }
```

In my usermodel

```
async findbyUsername(uNameorEmail: string) {
    const user = await this.userModel
      .findOne({ username: uNameorEmail })
      .lean()
      .exec();
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return user;
  }

  async findbyEmail(uNameorEmail: string) {
    const user = await this.userModel
      .findOne({ email: uNameorEmail })
      .lean()
      .exec();
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: https://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs

Comment: Remove `throw new NotFoundException();`

Comment: @hoangdv thanks. I see by removing the exceptions it works fine. Should I remove exceptions from my service file & only handle exception in controller? What is the correct way. Thanks

Comment: @curlygadfly_090 Yes.